# Visual Studio's console freezes

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple queue class in Visual Studio, and after I executed it, cmd(A.K.A console) just freezed( there wore no recursive methods and  there are no infinite loops, etc.). I cant' close it via  the Task Manager

Comment: If you think it's related to the code, it would be a great idea to share your code here. Otherwise, it's gonna be very difficult to help you.

Comment: You should share the code that caused this. Also, you can probably force Visual Studio to exit in the Task Manager. This will also close the console.

Comment: Sorry for the long response. I have deleted the code. But now I have a new question. What can cause cmd(A.K.A console) show the result of the code slowly??? What I mean is that I have a linked list, and when I run the code it shows me the console with no results, it only show a blinking cursor, and after a few seconds (5-7s.) it show the result, what can cause such a delay??? I have an "OK!" computer.